# Jackson doesnt care for the order of elements put in the Map

Tags: json, jackson

I am using Jackson library to generate JSON. 
I am passing an input map to the ObjectMapper

For eg. this is a code snippet of how I generate the map. I am adding groups,link,title to the Map. The JSON output has Objects in the order Link, Groups, Title.

```
Map beanMap = new HashMap();
beanMap=(keybean.getallSelectedViewGroups());
beanMap.put("Link",keybean.getHrefTex());
beanMap.put("Title",keybean.getTitle());
```

I used

```
mapper.writeValueAsString(beanMap) to generate the JSON String.
```

Even though it doesnt matter how the objects are ordered, just I am wondering what is the way to produce the JSON output in desired order.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers

Comment: Also, you can use SerializationFeature.ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Serialization-Features

Answer (score 7):

Depends on what "order" is for you. Jackson simply iterate entries in the map and outputs them to JSON. You can use `TreeMap` or `LinkedHashMap` instead, or use `SerializationFeature.ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS`.

Comment: LinkedHashMap helped. Thank you